# How to force a query to get the results with only all the rows selected?

Tags: mysql, sql

Well, it's a very simple question, so I hope you could help me.

I've two tables with this structure:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`products` (
  `id_product` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`features`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`features` (
  `id_feature` INT NOT NULL ,
  `id_product` INT NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_feature`) ,
  INDEX `fk_table2_table1` (`id_product` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_table2_table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_product` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`products` (`id_product` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

This query returns all the features of the product 5:

```
select descripcion from features where id_product = 5;
```

which are:

```
expensive
strong
tall
```

Ok, now I want to get all the names of the table 'products' that have **only all these features**.
I tried something like this:

```
select p.name from products p, features f
where p.id_product = f.id_product and
f.id_feature in 
(select id_feature from features 
where description in
(select description from features
where id_product = 5);
```

But it also gives me back the products which have less or more features than the three that I'm looking for...

I hope I was clear.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I please re-confirm that your description column has comma delimitted values? I wrote my query based on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are those products that have all three of those features that don't have any others.  If so, something like this should work:

```
SELECT P.Id_Product, P.Name
FROM Products P
    JOIN Features F ON P.id_product = F.id_product 
    JOIN Features F2 ON P.id_product = F2.id_product 
WHERE F.id_feature IN (SELECT id_feature FROM Features WHERE id_product = 5)
GROUP BY P.Id_Product, P.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT F2.id_Feature) = 3
```

And here is a condensed [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3c05/1) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use a join statement- i didn't check my query for exact syntax but you get the idea:

```
SELECT * FROM `mydb`.`products`
```

JOIN `mydb`.`features` ON `mydb`.`features`.`id_product` = `mydb`.`products`.`id_product`

```
WHERE

`mydb`.`features`.`description` = 'strong' OR
`mydb`.`features`.`description` = 'tall' OR
`mydb`.`features`.`description` = 'expensive';
```